# phonegap http error 404

Tags: android, ajax, cordova

I am trying to connect to server for fetching data using ajax call inside phonegap app.
But I am getting status 404 for every request I tried google.com, 10.0.2.2 (localhost on android).

Here are steps I followed for creating application

I created template application using phonegap command line as `phonegap create my-app`

Running application using `phonegap run android` ( This shows "device is ready" screen on emulator )

Added following code for making an Ajax call to index.js - receivedEvent function

```
var xmlhttp =  new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    console.log('rdy state - '+ xmlhttp.readyState);
    console.log('status - '+ xmlhttp.status);
    console.log('text status - '+ xmlhttp.statusText);
    console.log('Response Text - '+ xmlhttp.responseText);
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://10.0.2.2/", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

I can access `http://10.0.2.2` from emulator browser.

Here is Enviornment I am using

Phonegap version - 3.4.0-0.19.8
Android version - 4.4.2

-- Vishal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you put an access token in your config.xml? Try to put

```
<access origin="*"/>
```

into your `config.xml`.

`*` gives access to all domain.
Look up http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide for further information.

Comment: I am having this issue with Cordova but I have the wildcard. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Despite you have:

```
<pre> <access origin="*"/> </pre> in config.xml
```

You need to add the whitelist to your phonegap(cordova) project:

```
phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

After this your app will no longer give 404.